# How to count frequency of words under certain conditions in a PDF?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have a pdf which lists court cases and I have to find out the frequency of the mentioned paragraphs respectively. In particular I need to count example marked in red:

[image]

the first paragraph mentioned after the " | § " and only if it is mentioning "EStG" and not something like "AO" or "GewStG". And if it's possible sorting these results according to the year on the top left.

Thank you for any help!

I'm a beginner in R and also I haven't had much success in self educating myself in text mining etc. :/